# gi.repository Windows

Tags: python, windows, gtk, pygobject

I'm developing an app which has to be 100% compatible on windows and on linux. On linux I have no problems, but on windows I came up with this message:
from gi.repository import Gtk
ImportError: No module named gi

I installed pygobject, pygtkallinone, gtk.. what am I missing?

Comment: OMG that was quick, and it worked!! thanks :D

Comment: `gi` is for PyGObject, which is GTK+3, there each module is capitalized.  When you use `import gtk` you are using PyGTK (GTK+2).

Answer (score 20):

Most of Havok answer is correct, except that documentation has been improved a lot lately, with a Tutorial:

- http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Including a PDF version for offline reading:

- http://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/python-gtk-3-tutorial/latest/python-gtk-3-tutorial.pdf

And a complete API reference manual, not only of Gtk but also many other libraries that you can use with introspection:

- http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/

on windows the support is great, a lot of effort has been put in creating all the windows executables and libraries, the last release of pygi-aio is 3.10.6:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/?source=navbar

I've also put instructions on the Gnome wiki on how to build on win32 with pygobject introspection, it's not that hard, I've also uploaded a setup.py that actually works:

- https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/PyGObject?action=show&redirect=PyGObject#Building_on_Win32_with_cx_freeze

So the answer is, don't go with PyGTK

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Good to know that many things have improved over the years.

Comment: Great answer. The version of pygi-aio was even bumped to 3.14 a day ago.

Comment: The files given at `http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/?source=navbar` simply don't work.  The installer copy stuff, but no library is loadable by python when using `from gi.repository import Gtk`.

Comment: Apparently Python 3.5 isn't supported yet as we can read this in the readme.txt: `PyGI 3.18.2 AIO rev6 for python 2.7, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3 and 3.4 (32bit/64bit)` and `Python 3.5 port is WIP`.

Answer (score 15):

`gi.repository` module is called **PyGObject** and is for Gtk+3 and is not yet available for Windows (there has been experiments, but is not ready AFAIK). https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject

`gtk` module is called **PyGtk** and is for Gtk+2 and is very mature on Windows platforms (in particular 2.24). http://www.pygtk.org/

What's the difference?

- PyGObject has some scarse Windows support. PyGtk has great support for this OS.
- PyGObject is what is called a dynamic binding and PyGtk is a static one.
- PyGObject is new and the future and PyGtk is the past, mature and some day will be deprecated.
- PyGObject documentation and examples are very very limited, and PyGtk one are very very complete: http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/
- They are not compatible, you can't use both and you need to choose one.
- PyGObject is in active development, no new features will be introduced for PyGtk.
- If you use Glade, the lastest version will be for PyGObject (for example 3.12.1). If you want to use Glade for PyGtk install the 3.8.0 version.

If you choose to go PyGtk there is great support for freezing the application. You can check  my documentation and support files for my application here: http://sourceforge.net/p/nestededitor/code/247/tree/trunk/dist/windows/

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**

Many things have changed in two years. Please see gianmt answer.

Comment: are there any problems with freezing PyGTK applications using [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)? py2exe is Windows only

Comment: Never tested with PyInstaller, sorry.

Comment: PyGObject has some documentation, that ain't that bad: http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Yes, the documentation is getting better and better, but that's a tutorial, not an API reference. You can't do serious programming in PyGObject without an API reference, because you need to know all the functions, variables, signal, etc, available. Good API documentation is this one http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ (for C) or http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/ (for old PyGtk), PyGObject the best it has now is this http://people.gnome.org/~johnp/girdocsalpha/Gtk/. With time, tools for generation of the documentation will improve and allow to program in PyGObject.

Comment: Released: January 27, 2013 pygi-3.4.2_gtk+-3.6.4.7z

http://opensourcepack.blogspot.de/p/pygobject-pygi-aio.html