# Is there an easier way to understand how to install pygobject + gtk+3?

Tags: gtk, pygobject

As a beginner I like the look and the code style of GTK+3 and the tutorial.
The problem is that I can't understand how to install it.
https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/PyGObject?action=show&redirect=PyGObject
https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Until now I have failed.
For the meantime I started playing with PyQT and wxpython and see what is best.
At least they are much easier to intall even PyQt is hard to code for me and wxpython is less attractive when it comes to looks.

Comment: Do you want to install from source? Why is it difficult? Which OS?

Comment: my OS is windows 7.

I admit that i'm too noob to deal with this technical complicated installations.
Its a pity there is no simple installation as it is with PyQt and wxPython.

One thing i like with GTK is that the coding style is very similar to Tkinter and i love Tkinter but i want to do more complex things so i need a new library

So i started to read about PyQT and play with it and later i'll try wxpython and see what is better for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your best shot is to use a Linux distribution, a Debian based one is your best option for easy installation. In Ubuntu, for example, GTK3, PyGObject and Python are all installed by default. Don't download and compile from the GTK website.

If you really need to use a Windows OS, your best option is to use:

http://opensourcepack.blogspot.de/p/pygobject-pygi-aio.html

But be warned, you will have problems, because is not that easy either, and IMHO, Gtk+3 is not ready for multiplatform development yet, or at least as ready as Gtk+2 was. See [gi.repository Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981137/gi-repository-windows/12986596#12986596)

For the prime time pygobject still needs:

- And API reference. There is no auto-generated documentation yet. And using the C reference is just guessing most of the time.
- Official installers for Windows.
- Support for Python3/PyGObject application freeze.
- That Gtk+3 actually works and looks as expected in other OSs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Its only strengthening my general impression i got when reading and trying GTK+3.
For the mean time i trying pyqt and later will try wxpython.

Answer (score 0):

I want to update the status of PyGObject for Windows because @Havok seems link to his own answer from a year ago.

currently:

- Python API reference will be available (in CHM), please note that in linux it used to behave like valadoc (server <-> client) with html generated on-he-fly but since no libyelp for windows, it need to be converted to static html and it takes a lot of time to render 30000+ files using gnome-doc-tool under MSYS.
- IMO There is no strict requirement for installer availability to be usable.
- Application freeze is possible (personally tested with py2exe) and via cx_freeze tested and documented by Tagliaretti (see PyGObject wiki)
- It actually works, and has been continuously tested against two complex/popular application under Windows: MyPaint by me and Gramps by Helge. In fact the AIO package is far more complete compared to any PyGTK AIO.

Stability is still a concern though, but then GTK2 also has some bad releases as well such 2.18.0 - 2.24.7. It's a matter of avoiding buggy GDK.

My answer maybe biased though.