# minimize to tray, stuck in loop, python gtk

Tags: python, linux, pygobject

python: 2.7.5

os: linux, fedora 19

this is a minimum example code to show the problem that i am having, the tray part of the code is excluded cause it is working fine.

run it in a terminal, when the minimize button is press, it enter a `show()` and `hide()` loop

i think the easiest way to show it is to make it print a number every it show or hide itself.

the question is: how do i get it to work correctly without it getting stuck in a loop?

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class Win(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.connect("delete-event", self.delete_event)
        #something to make it easier to see the loop
        self.num = 0
        self.connect('window-state-event', self.window_state_event_cb)

    def window_state_event_cb(self, widget, event):
       if event.changed_mask & Gdk.WindowState.ICONIFIED:
          if event.new_window_state & Gdk.WindowState.ICONIFIED:
             self.hide()
             print 'Window was minimized!'
          else:
             self.show()
             print 'Window was unminimized!'
          self.num += 1
          print(self.num)

    def delete_event(self,window,event):
        Gtk.main_quit()

if __name__=="__main__":
    win = Win()
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

code pieced together from http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=edit&file=faq10.022.htp

Comment: In which scenario does it get stuck in a loop?

Comment: `when the minimize button is press`

Comment: I tried the code you posted with pygtk-2.24.2 and it minimizes without getting stuck. Try removing/disabling all other event handlers and test if the code you posted actually loops on its own.

Comment: it's looping on linux, maybe it's a linux thing but i doubt it, did you run it in the terminal/command line?

Comment: Yes command line as `python filename.py` where I pasted your code and adjusted imports etc for my pygtk version. Might be linux (I'm on win), might be your gtk version...

Comment: my mistake, pygtk and gi are different, but they both are gtk, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12986596/1986995

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and this works for me.

```
def on_windowStateEvent(self, widget, event):
  if (event.changed_mask & Gdk.WindowState.ICONIFIED):
    if (event.new_window_state & Gdk.WindowState.ICONIFIED):
      # minimize visible widow. We hide the window to remove it
      # from the active tasks windows, a click the tray icon will
      # bring it back
      self.window.hide()
    else:
      # don't do anything here. The call from hide() above causes a 
      # new event that ends here. And calling show() now will result
      # in a loop
      pass

def statusIcon_activate(self, statusIcon):
  # restore the hidden window on a click on the tray icon
  self.window.deiconify()
  self.window.present() # present the window on the active desktop

...
self.window = Gtk.Window()
self.window.connect("window-state-event", self.on_windowStateEvent)
....
self.statusIcon = Gtk.StatusIcon()
self.statusIcon.connect("activate", self.statusIcon_activate)
...
```

And there is the short form:

```
def isEventIconify(event):
  return (event.changed_mask
          & event.new_window_state
          & Gdk.WindowState.ICONIFIED)

def on_windowStateEvent(self, widget, event):
  if isEventIconify(event):
    self.window.hide()
```

Comment: The nested `if` is redundant. You just need to `and` the conditions together. Given you're already doing bit twiddling, you might be able to just `&` all three together (`event.changed_mask`, `event.new_window_state`, and `Gdk.WindowState.ICONIFIED`), but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: True, but this was meant as a very verbose example based on the code above and the code references in the PyGTK FAQ. It still keeps the places where to add more code given one wants to make the "minimize to tray" feature configurable.