# Python GI module cannot be imported

Tags: module, windows-7, python-3.5

Can someone please guide me on what I can do to correct this error?
There are quite few solutions available but i am totally confused (I am not so experienced with python) and so I thought maybe I could ask here to find a solution!
Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: We really need to know more about how you got gi installed otherwise we wont know why its missing...did you follow the installation guide here? http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Comment: @D219 But my OS is windows and it says only for linux i think so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should possibly take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981137/gi-repository-windows) these guys cover a lot of what you are looking for if you are trying to use gtk from python on windows. However it also does depend on your python version by the looks of it too since i see you are using python version 3.5...the bindings may not exist yet, however i am unsure, perhaps if you completely build from the source code.